# Which characters are not allowed in Java 9 module names?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Dashes are not allowed in the JPMS module names. As I understand it is suggested to replace them with dots.

However I cannot find a list of other not allowed characters in Java modules names with replacement suggestions. For example, is "_" character allowed?

Comment: Closely related [How should I name my Java 9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192741/how-should-i-name-my-java-9-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java Language Specification, section [7.7. Module Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7), says:

> A module name consists of one or more Java identifiers ([§3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)) separated by "`.`" tokens.

So the valid characters for a module name is the same as for the fully qualified name of a class.