# The error message suggests that there is a problem with finding the module com.example.demo3 during the initialization of the Java application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, lib, intellij-13

The error message suggests that there is a problem with finding the module com.example.demo3 during the initialization of the Java application.

> VM : "--module-path "C:\java\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

the error:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\java\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=53786:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\SUNLIGHT COMPUTER.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\20\javafx-controls-20.jar;C:\Users\SUNLIGHT COMPUTER.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\20\javafx-graphics-20.jar;C:\Users\SUNLIGHT COMPUTER.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\20\javafx-base-20.jar;C:\Users\SUNLIGHT COMPUTER.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\20\javafx-fxml-20.jar" -m com.example.demo3/com.example.demo3.HelloApplication
> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.example.demo3 not found
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Did you create `module-info.java` file that defines a module named `com.example.demo3`?  Is it in the root path of the module?    Read [understanding modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: For reference, the `javafx-maven-archetypes` cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276885/230513) both create a `module-info.java` in the context of a working example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.