# How to create a runnable Jar file with dependencies from Netbeans Maven JavaFx project

Tags: maven, javafx, netbeans, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have created a new JavaFx Maven project with Netbeans:
[image: creating new JavaFx Maveb project]
and my project also includes dependencies. Now I want to build my project into a runnable Jar file.
I tried using the Maven assembly plugin. Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject2.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject2.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>  this is used for inheritance merges 
                    <phase>package</phase>  bind to the packaging phase 
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the following error:
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I have tried various approaches, for instance just running build. This creates a jar file however it says main class not specified. I have also tried using the Maven jar plugin, but I got the same error. I want to have a single jar file which contains all my javafx and other dependencies.

Comment: I use the `javafx-maven-plugin` to run `javafx:jlink`. A complete [example](https://github.com/trashgod/modular), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276885/230513) and using the same archetype, illustrates several [ways forward](https://github.com/trashgod/modular/wiki#running). See the [tag:javafx] tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for other deployment strategies.