# JavaFX build generating a blank gui with primary view and secondary view buttons

Tags: maven, javafx

I am using JavaFX for the first time for my homework assignments. So far, I have had around 5 homework questions that use JavaFX and only one has worked. The others all just show a white screen with 2 buttons, one saying Switch to Primary View and one saying Switch to Secondary View. I have no idea what is causing this or how to fix it. Are there any resources I can use to learn more about what is causing this issue, or any help someone can offer? I am using jdk 21.

My code was giving me an error about Stage requiring transitive and some other guy on here asked about that so I did what the comment said and the error is gone but it didn't change the output.

Comment: The [`javafx-archetype-fxml`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes) archetype creates just such an application; the corresponding `javafx-archetype-simple` archetype is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276885/230513).

Comment: @trashgod What does that mean?

Comment: In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276885/230513), change `javafx-archetype-simple` to `javafx-archetype-fxml`.

Comment: module assignment.twenty.nine {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    opens assignment.twenty.nine to javafx.fxml;
    exports assignment.twenty.nine;
}
Is this what you mean? With the javafx.fxml thing? Also, should I be doing a requires for every import I make? I have like 15-20 imports but only require like 5 of them.

Comment: When you generate the archetype, as shown, you should get the example seen [here](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes/tree/master/javafx-archetype-fxml/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java); compare the result to your code; please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach..

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. Also include the exact version of Java you're using, the exact version of JavaFX you're using, the OS that you're using, the version of the OS, etc.

Comment: Create and post a [mre]. Otherwise you are just encouraging people to guess, instead of actually provide answers that solve your problem.